# Firebase Invites on iOS and Android - Is it possible to generate the Share Links without showing the UI?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-invites

[Firebase Invites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/) seems to come with a UI for creating referral links on iOS and Android. Since we're making a game we'd like to use our own UI (and at least optionally skip showing the standard system UI).

Is it possible to programmatically just copy the referral link to the clipboard without ever showing the Invite UI?

Answer (score 5):

Firebase Invites is a UI to create dynamic links.

For creating such links in your own code, use [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/) - which Invites uses under the hood.

Comment: Thank you! I was just wondering if Invites would easify that creation of Dynamic Links with some helper functions or similar.